# Can I use TI Launchpad's JTAG debugger to debug Raspberry Pi over JTAG?

Tags: hardware, debug

[This tutorial](http://sysprogs.com/VisualKernel/tutorials/raspberry/jtagsetup/) describes settting up Rapsberry Pi for debugging over ARM JTAG.

[TI LaunchPad](http://www.ti.com/ww/en/launchpad/launchpad.html?DCMP=TIMDC_in&HQS=TIMDC-launchpad) board also contains some JTAG things to [program](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/JTAG_%28MSP430%29) MSP430.

It has only [two wires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spy-Bi-Wire), unlike eight in the tutorial, so naive way is likely to fail. Is there any easy way to make it work?

Comment: Should the question "How do I JTAG-debug one Raspberry Pi using the other Raspberry Pi" be separate one or integrated into this?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange rpi. Please tell us more. What did you try so far? Also, if you can include the relevant parts of the links into the question itself, it will make more people actually read the question (becase who can be bothered to click on four links, really? ;) ).

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I've just saw the word "JTAG" both in RPi and TI Launchpad, so asking if they can be combined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first tutorial describes setting up RPi for **debugging**, the second explains how to use JTAG to **program** MSP430. A slight difference that explains where are those extra wires going. Besides that, MSP430 JTAG support is very limited and could not be used with fully JTAG-compatible devices.

You might (though very unlikely) get away with two wires if your goal is only to program your RPi, but what's the point? Wires are not expensive nor hard to find, use as much as explained in the tutorial and be safe.

Comment: No, it's not about programming MSP430 using Rapberry Pi. It's about "programming" Rapberry Pi with a debugging board desiged for MSP430. The process of debugging MSP430 using that board is easy and streamlined. Can this ease be transferred to RPi as well?

Comment: `MSP430 JTAG support is very limited` -> so the other side's (programmer's) JTAG support is likewise limited, therefore "TI Launchpad's JTAG debugger" is not a fully fledged JTAG, just MSP430-specific and I should not try using it for non-MSP430. Right?